# ActiveDirectory Update a user getting UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: security, active-directory

I have a script that updates user pictures.  It works perfectly fine on my machine as I'm a Domain Admin.  I want to schedule it to run on my SQL Server, but the account that is running the Agent service doesn't have the correct privileges (obviously).  I'm wondering what is the least that I have to grant this account in order to get my script to work.  I always could use the brute force approach and make it a domain admin, but I'd rather not.

Thanks,

Update:  Here's a snippit of the code that does it:

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry e;  // Gotten from query earlier
e.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Add(bytes); // Bytes is an array of bytes that make up the picture          
e.Properties["jpegPhoto"].Add(bytes);
e.CommitChanges();   // Fails here
```

Again.. .it works perfectly fine when run as a Domain Admin.

Comment: We need more info.  What "user pictures" are you trying to update exactly?  What kind of "script" is it, an SQL script?  What is the Agent service actually being denied access to?

Comment: I'm updating the thumbnailPhoto and jpegPhoto properties of the directoryEntry property through a c# script.  When I call "CommitChanges", however, I get the UnauthorizedException.  I'll post some code if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This covers thunbnailPhoto specifically, but jpegPhoto (and other property) access can be granted the same way...

You must **Delegate Control** to the assigned user, granting them read and write access to the Active Directory attribute "thumbnailPhoto".

1. Load "*Active Directory Users and Computers*" Management Console (dsa.msc).
2. Right click on the Domain or Organizational Unit containing the Domain Users that you would like your assigned user to be able to upload pictures for and select "*Delegate Control*". The "Delegation of Control Wizard" will be displayed on the screen. Click Next:

[image]

3. Click the "Add" button to add the user(s) or group who you would like to grant permissions to change the Outlook Photo to and click Next.
4. On the "Task to Delegate" page click the radio button "Create a custom task to delegate". Click Next:

[image]

5. On the "Active Directory Object Type" page choose the radio button "Only the following objects in the folder" and tick the check box "User objects". Click Next:

[image]

6. On the "Permissions" page tick the check box "Property-specific" then in the permissions list tick the boxes for "Read thumbnail Photo" and "Write thumbnailPhoto". Click Next:

[image]

7.Click "Finish" to complete the "Delegation of Control Wizard".

The assigned user(s) or group will now be able to read and write to the "thumbnailPhoto" attribute. For the permission changes to take effect, the user(s) will be required to log off and then logon.

[Source](http://www.exclaimer.ca/support/knowledge-base/how-do-i-delegate-control-of-the-thumbnail-photo-field)